# Dynamically adding js to asp.net file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my Page_Load I identify the page header block from my master page and add javascript from an XML file to that part of the page.

It doesn't seem to be loading in time. If I explicitly put the script reference on the page, it works. But not when I load through the page_load event.

Should it be loaded sooner?

Comment: JavaScript code/file is loaded and its content will be executed by web-browser. You should add `<script/>` block in `<head>` tag.

Comment: please show us the code, and the rendered code, and what you look for. It very unclear what its your real issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not adding any code so I'm not able to tell you what you're doing wrong. Instead, I'll tell you a valid way to add script references from code behind.

Something like this on `Page_Load` should do the trick

```
var js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
js.Attributes["src"] = "myFile.js";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(js);
```

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing. And it works locally through Visual Studio. When I deploy to my development server, I see the links in the correct place through "view page source", but the functionality doesn't work and I get js errors in IE.

Comment: @Michael Warren: then probably files paths are wrong. Please add the path you see for the js file when you do "view source" and where the file is physically placed.

Comment: That was it! thanks so much. VS must know how to resolve an incorrect path.

Answer (score 0):

You can't you put in  following method in ur page,

```
protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this here i have js folder on root and it work fine for me.

```
function addJavascript(jsname, pos) {
            var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            s.setAttribute('src', jsname);
            th.appendChild(s);

        }

 addJavascript('js/table.js', 'Head');
```

call addJavascript method with file path and parent tag where you want to add javascript file

Hope it works for you..