# How do I reference code in dynamically added js files?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to add js files dynamically.
I found several guides for that and in Page inspector, they all seem like they work…
However, I cannot reference any code in the newly added files.

[image]

My three code examples that look like they work fine... but don't.

```
//v1
var th = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src', scriptName);
th.appendChild(s);
DevExpress.localization.loadMessages(RddsDataNavigator_LanguagePack_en);

//v2
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', scriptName);
document.head.appendChild(s);
DevExpress.localization.loadMessages(RddsDataNavigator_LanguagePack_en);

//v3
let myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.setAttribute("src", scriptName);
document.head.appendChild(myScript);
DevExpress.localization.loadMessages(RddsDataNavigator_LanguagePack_en);
```

do i have to append the scripts differently or is my reference call wrong / not possible?

the Guides that exactly explain my requirement seem somehow not to work for me ?! 
https://www.kirupa.com/html5/loading_script_files_dynamically.htm 
[Dynamically adding js to asp.net file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101182/dynamically-adding-js-to-asp-net-file)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you check in network, if your scripts are getting loaded or not?

Comment: What does *I cannot reference any code* mean? How do your "reference" this code? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Dynamically added scripts are loaded asynchronously, you've to wait for them to be loaded before you can access variables in the scripts.

Comment: my Code examples show the loading and as last line the reference call. how could i wait for the loading to finish before referencing it ?

Comment: If you add script elements dynamically *on page load*, then wait for the `DOMContentLoadad` event.

Comment: on page load and DOMContentLoadad work for the error exception but not for my code structure. the scripts i load are for Localization and are required in body before DOMContentLoadad triggers. is there any other event or an easy way to rebuild the body after DOMContentLoadad?

Comment: Indeed, it should be the load event. See my answer.

Comment: Technically this question is answered. I continued my follow up problems in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809316/html-load-order-and-dynamically-added-js-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three methods to add a script element are essentially the same<sup>*</sup>.

As dynamically added script elements do not load the resources synchronously, you need to listen to the `load` event on the global object. `DOMContentLoaded` is another idea, but it fires too soon as it does not wait for resources to have loaded.

Here is a demo with loading jQuery asynchronously. The output shows the type of the `jQuery` variable, which will be "function" once that resource is loaded:

```js
let scriptName = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js";
// v3
let myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.setAttribute("src", scriptName);
document.head.appendChild(myScript);

console.log("Synchronous, jQuery =", typeof jQuery);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("After DOMContentLoaded event, jQuery =", typeof jQuery);
});
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log("After load event, jQuery =", typeof jQuery);
});
```

---

<sub>* The first version also defines the type attribute, but the HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the attribute rather than provide a redundant MIME type.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Consider this working example:

```js
//  dyn.js
window.zzz = 1;
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function includeJs(url)
    {
        if (!url) throw "Invalid argument url";
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
    includeJs("dyn.js");

    function documentLoaded()
    {
        alert(window.zzz)
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:documentLoaded()">
</body>
</html>
```

An obvious difference between your code and this is that the sample above loads the script *during* the document loading and the usage of the script code happens *after* the document has finished loading.

If you need to do a late-loading of a dynamic script depending on some run-time parameters, here are some options:

If you have control over the dynamically-loading script, you could add a function in your loader script and call it at the last line of the dynamically-loading script:

```js
//  dyn.js
window.zzz = 1;
if(typeof(dynamicLoadingFinished) != "undefined") dynamicLoadingFinished();
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function includeJs(url)
    {
        if (!url) throw "Invalid argument url";
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
    function documentLoaded()
    {
        includeJs("dyn.js");
        window.dynamicLoadingFinished = function()
        {
           alert(window.zzz)
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:documentLoaded()">
</body>
</html>
```

Another possible approach would be to use the good old `XMLHttpRequest`. It will allow you yo either force synchronous loading (which is not advisable because it will block all JavaScript and interactivity during loading, but in certain situations can be of use):

```css
//  dyn.js
window.zzz = 1;
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function includeJs(url)
    {
        if (!url) throw "Invalid argument url";
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, false);
        request.send();

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.text = request.responseText;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
    function documentLoaded()
    {
        includeJs("dyn.js");
        alert(window.zzz)
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:documentLoaded()">
</body>
</html>
```

or load the script asynchronously and wait for the request to finish:

```css
//  dyn.js
window.zzz = 1;
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function includeJs(url, finished)
    {
        if (!url) throw "Invalid argument url";
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (request.readyState == 4 || request.readyState == 0)
            {
                if (request.status == "200")
                {
                    var script = document.createElement("script");
                    script.text = request.responseText;
                    document.head.appendChild(script);
                    return finished();
                }
                else throw request.responseText;
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
    function documentLoaded()
    {
        includeJs("dyn.js", () => alert(window.zzz));
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:documentLoaded()">
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the AJAX samples could be written also with the more modern `fetch` API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Technically this question is answered. I continued my follow up problems in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809316/html-load-order-and-dynamically-added-js-files