# HTML load order and dynamically added JS Files

Tags: javascript, html

I add some JS files dynamically to my HTML Header and I want to guarantee that my JS files finish loading before I continue to render my Body.
Events like load or DOMContentLoaded trigger after the loading is finished.
my body needs the added scripts to render properly but starts before the files are loaded fully.

Code Snippet:

```
    ...
    <script>

            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetLocalisationFiles", "Localisation")',
                success: function (response) {
                        for (var file in response) {
                            var scriptName = response[file];
                            //Adding of the script(s)
                            let myScript = document.createElement("script");
                            myScript.setAttribute("src", scriptName);
                            document.head.appendChild(myScript);
                            //
                        }
                }
            });

        window.addEventListener("load", LocalizationAdded);
        function LocalizationAdded(e) {
            alert("JS Files Finished Loading");
            DevExpress.localization.loadMessages(RddsDataNavigator_LanguagePack_en);

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body class="dx-viewport">
    <script>
        alert("Body Started"); 
        ...
```

Is there any other event prior to the rendering of the body or an easy way to delay my body rendering?
I know I could manually add all Content that depends on the added scripts after the loading is finished but this seems fuzzy.
The dynamical adding of JS works as intended. My Problem is within the order it happens.

Thanks in advance for any help

Previous question:
[How do I reference code in dynamically added js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806351/how-do-i-reference-code-in-dynamically-added-js-files)

Comment: Why is it necessary to make an AJAX call for fetching the list of the scripts? Can't you get the same list of scripts while generating the HTML on server-side?

Comment: Side note: `async: false` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm new to Web Development. I use ASP.NET Core and MVC Template. I guess if i prebuild the file on server side it would solve all my Problems but i have no clue how to do that. i will give it a try and read into it.

Comment: In web development everybody is trying to avoid the blocking of rendering of pages as much as possible for faster page loads. You want to achieve de opposite :)

Comment: Jokes aside, I do not think that using AJAX to get the list of the JS files to be loaded is the solution. I cannot easily think of a use-case where this solution would be preferable / easier than including those script tags on server-side.

Comment: Also, on your other thread I saw you are loading localization files for multiple languages. Unless your website is a translation tool, you won't need more than one language loaded at a time.

Comment: Well, my goal is to implement the ECMAScript Internationalization API for localization. A single Hosted Page will need only 2-4 Localizations but overall, I have to provide several language packages.
In my Current understanding it seems bad if I provide 30 Languages and handle the localisation on Clint side and it seems also bad if I provide every single translation via controller call. The Components default provided Localisations are JS files and I thought with my attempt I could only provide the once necessary for the current hosting/user. I guess i have to look up some more basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could question whether loading scripts following some user action, is such a good idea. You could instead load the relevant HTML content from the server (which could include script tags), if you really want to have a one-page experience, or else initiate a navigation, where again the server would get clues via HTTP request on what to generate next.

But, if we stick with this pattern, I would suggest using the `onload` property of script elements, and to use promises for awaiting all scripts to have been loaded.

Here is some code you could use. This demo loads two JS files after an AJAX call has come back with a response: one for the immutablejs library, the second for the momentjs library.

A `new Promise` will resolve when the script's `load` event fires, and `Promise.all` will resolve when this has happened for *all* scripts.

For the purpose of demo I replaced the URL with a mock, and also tampered with the response in order to produce a response as you have it:

```js
// dummy server, just for demo
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
console.log("Launching initial HTTP request...");
$.get(url).then(function (response) {
    console.log("Received response. Loading scripts...");
    // Overwriting the response with mock data:
    response = {
        immutable: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js",
        moment: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"
    };
    return Promise.all(Object.values(response).map(function (scriptName) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
            //Adding of the script(s)
            let myScript = document.createElement("script");
            myScript.setAttribute("src", scriptName);
            myScript.onload = resolve;
            myScript.onerror = reject;
            document.head.appendChild(myScript);
            //
        });
    }));
}).then(function () {
    // All code that depends on the loaded scripts should be here, or called from here
    console.log("All scripts loaded:");
    console.log("Immutable: ", typeof Immutable);
    console.log("moment: ", typeof moment);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remark: the `async: false` option is deprecated. It is not good practice either. Instead use the Promise that jQuery returns for `$.ajax`, `$.get`, ...etc, and chain a `then` call where you continue processing the result (instead of a `success` handler). And on once you arrive in the world of promises, you'll find that using `async` and `await` syntax can simplify code.